# Mozilla Daaon: exchange variables between main.js -> MyContent.js -> MyScripts.js

Tags: firefox-addon

I' writing a addon that add functionality to a site.
But I need to parse variables between .js

**main.js:**

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: ["*"],
  contentScriptWhen: 'end',
  contentScriptFile: data.url("MyContent.js"),
  contentScriptOptions: {
    showOptions: true,
    dataUrl: data.url("MyContent.js") // To parse the URL-Path
  }
  });
```

**MyContent.js:**

```
//to read the URL like resource://.....:
var dataUrl=self.options.dataUrl.substring(0,self.options.dataUrl.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = dataUrl+"scripts.js";
window.document.head.appendChild(script);
```

The variable dataUrl exist in MyContent.js but not in MyScripts.js
I need the variable dataUrl in MyScripts.js to know the url for some images saved in the data-folder.
How can I define global variables that can been accessed from all scripts?
with worker can I comunicate between main.js and MyContent.js, but not with MyScripts.js

Comment: Hi @user2215119 did you find the solution, if yes then can you please share it, so that others get benefited. I am also looking for solutions to this kind problem something like this.